# socket.io server keeps getting connection event but client side never connects

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I have the following code for client side in a node project

```
const openSocket = require('socket.io-client');

const socket = openSocket('http://localhost:2345');

console.log(socket.connected,socket.id)

socket.on('connect', function () { console.log('connect') });
socket.on('event', function (data) { console.log('event') });
socket.on('error', function (error) { console.log('error') });
socket.on('disconnect', function () { console.log('disconnect') });
socket.on('connection', (socket) => { console.log('connection') })
socket.on('fdaTrigger', (data) => { console.log('fdaTrigger') })
```

On the server side, I have socket.io running on port 2345

```
const io = require('socket.io')(server, {
  perMessageDeflate: false,
  pingInterval: 10000,
  pingTimeout: 5000,
});
var debug = require('debug')('socket.io');
var assetCounter = -1;
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  assetCounter = -1;
  debug('Started');
  console.log('Got a connection', socket.connected, socket.id);
})
```

The connection event is fired every few seconds on server but my client refuses to connect. When I stop running the client code, the connections stop, so it's connecting but client side does not connect. Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: I find this question confusing, "...Its connecting but client side does not connect.."? can you clarify?

Comment: Btw. If your client is served at same domain as server, you dont have to specify url.. so you can go const io = require('socket.io-client'); const socket = io(); ... try this first

Comment: @kerim092 connect event is not being fired on client. but connection event keeps getting fired,every few secods

Comment: Update : The issue was due to version difference. listening to 'connect_error' did give a log

Answer (score 0):

Try Below Code

Client Side

```
const openSocket = require('socket.io-client');
const socket = openSocket('http://localhost:2345', {transports: ['websocket']});
setTimeout(() => {
  console.log(socket.connected,socket.id)
}, 100)
socket.on('connect', function () { console.log('connect') });
socket.on('event', function (data) { console.log('event') });
socket.on('error', function (error) { console.log('error') });
socket.on('disconnect', function () { console.log('disconnect') });
socket.on('connection', (socket) => { console.log('connection') })
socket.on('fdaTrigger', (data) => { console.log('fdaTrigger') })
```

Server Side

```
const server = require("http").createServer(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(server, {
   perMessageDeflate: false,
   pingInterval: 10000,
   pingTimeout: 5000,
});
var debug = require('debug')('socket.io');
var assetCounter = -1;
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
   assetCounter = -1;
   debug('Started');
   console.log('Got a connection', socket.connected, socket.id);
})
const port = 2345;
server.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`));
```